# Location Radius within a Geolocation cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have a test app which checks if the user is in an area in the world i specify. If the user is in this area the app would alert you're here. At the moment my app isn't very accurate. Is there a better way? Should i use something like this? http://www.geomidpoint.com/random/ For setting points around my area? What would you suggest me?

This is what i have:

```
function onSuccess(position) {
    $("#geolocation").html('Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' + "<hr>");

    if (position.coords.latitude > 47.999999 - 500 && position.coords.latitude < 47.999999 + 500 &&position.coords.longitude >= 7.999999 - 500 && position.coords.longitude < 7.999999 + 500 ) {
      alert("Unlocked");
    }
}



function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { timeout: 30000 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, your app will not run if it is in the background.

I'm just developing an app, which has an similar approach and I use this plugin for geofence:

http://plugreg.com/plugin/tsubik/cordova-plugin-geofence

The plugin generates notifications but there is also a function for catching transitions if your app is in the foreground.

The plugin is working very well, I'm just testing it on the canary islands.